# UART Tx stops working without UART Rx connected

Tags: microcontroller, pic, serial, uart, microchip

So my problem is that when I have both Tx and Rx connected to an FTDI cable with ground connected as well. When I have both cables connected I can send message as expected. But as soon as I disconnect the Rx cable the transmissions stop and I have to restart the device in order to get it going again. Just reconnecting the Rx cable doesn't work.

Im using a PIC processor that I transmit from and I use Putty to monitor the data.

Summary

- All cables connected
- Send data in endless loop ( works fine )
- Disconnect the Rx cable -> all transmissions stops

As far as I've understood I should not need the Rx cable to be connected at all since the uart is configured to be asynchronous. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Did you  consider posting cable drawing? who knows what is actually connected there...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'tx' and 'rx', and in which direction are you sending the data?

Comment: When I'm talking about Tx/Rx cable I mean the cables from the PIC processor. Pic Tx is connected to FTDI Rx and PIC Rx is connected to FTDI Tx. I'm sending the data from the PIC to the FTDI ( so I can see the data in Putty )

Comment: Did you connect the GND? Perhaps not, so your RX line shares some potential, enough to make TX working.

Comment: Yes GND is connected as written in the post

Comment: If I reset the PIC it seams like it can transmit data for just a second, because ~7 correct bytes are recieved and then everything just stops. This is if I only connect the Tx cable

Comment: You should not need to connect to rx at all.  What if you disable uart rx in the pic (if possible not all uarts have separate tx and rx enables).  i assume you have not enabled any flow control?

Comment: No flowcontrol is enabled indeed. I too agree with that I should not need to even have the Rx cable

Comment: Could pulling out your Rx cable present a transient to the microcontroller that knocks it over? I've seen that happen though your circumstances could be different. It's a quick enough experiment to put a 47 nF or 100 nF capacitor across your Rx-GND and Tx-GND then yank the cable out again. Just an idea if you get to that stage :-)

Comment: Is RX left floating when it's not connected?  Could it be picking up crosstalk from the TX signal?  Is the RX IRQ enabled?  If so are you handling and clearing the RX IRQ or is the code getting stuck in it?  Use the debugger to figure out where the code is stuck.

Comment: Show us your UART IRQ code. But I'm going to guess that you're not handling RX errors correctly and your PIC is therefore stuck in the RX IRQ handler.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the RX Interrupt goes into an infinite loop of unhandled interrupts or an overrun or frame error occurs. To protect against that, flush the receive buffer and reset the UART if this occurs. i.e. put this into the RXInterrupt code

```
if (PIR1bits.RC1IF)
{
  PIR1bits.RC1IF = 0;

  if ((RCSTAbits.OERR) || (RCSTAbits.FERR))
  {
    // Resets UART
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 0;
    Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1;

    // Clears RX Buffer
    RCREG;
    RCREG;
  }
}
```

Comment: A good chance of this being the problem, or one of many.